# objective c simple calculator questions about addNumber instance method

Tags: objective-c, instance-methods

```
   - (IBAction)addButton; {
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        UIButton *numberButton = [UIButton buttonWithType : UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [numberButton addTarget:self action:@selector(numberSelected:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [numberButton setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

        if (i<1) {
            numberButton.frame = CGRectMake(29, 367.5, 58,50);
        }
        if (i>=1 && i<4) {
            numberButton.frame = CGRectMake((i*.5)*(58/i)+68*(i-1), 332.5, 58,50);
        }
        if (i>=4 && i<7) {
            numberButton.frame = CGRectMake((i*.5)*(58/i)+68*(i-4), 297.5, 58,50);
        }
        if (i>=7 && i<10) {
            numberButton.frame = CGRectMake((i*.5)*(58/i)+68*(i-7), 262.5, 58,50);
        }

        [self.view addSubview:numberButton];

    }
```

Here is some code from a simple calculator this is a instance method where the buttons are being created and positioned on the display. MY questions:

1. the .frame in the statement numberButton.frame ... what is that doing? why is it necessary?
2. in this statement  `[numberButton addTarget:self action:@selector(numberSelected:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` is it saying when a button is touched inside it will send the int value initialized in the for loop to numberSelected method declared in the header file?

Thank you for your time MICHAEL.

Answer (score 0):

1. By `numberButton.frame` you are setting the frame of your button by telling your button how to position itself on the screen.

For Instance, `CGRectMake(29, 367.5, 58,50)` is saying that on screen your button's starting position in it's superview is x = 29 and y = 367.5 and the size is, more specifically, the width is 58 and height is 50.

It is necessary to specify explicitely as your controller doesn't know how to create your button meaning what will be it's size or starting position. If you don't specify this, you will have a button with 0 height and 0 width and probably from a (0, 0) position.

2. [numberButton addTarget:self action:@selector(numberSelected:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

This statement is saying when you press/hit the button, it should call a method named numberSelected and that method has a parameter which is the instance of the button itself. So, basically somewhere in the same controller class, you have a method with a signature like-

```
-(void) numberSelected:(UIButton*)sender;
```

The int value that you create inside the loop has nothing to do with this method. You are not passing that int value, you are passing the button, itself as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read a lot of Apple documentation, before turning immediately to Stack Overflow for assistance. You seem confused about things that are very clearly and cleanly described there.

But, to answer your questions directly:

1. The "frame" of a UIView describes its position within its superview, meaning the view it is contained within. Views can contain other views which contain other views, nested together. Similar to a picture in a picture frame, you have a picture (your button), and you need to tell the system where to put that picture on the wall (the window, in this simple case).
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html
2. Your second method uses `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to say, "When the user **touches** this button, and **lifts up** while still **inside the button**'s (touch...up...inside) on-screen area", then it should call the method named "numberSelected:". This distinguishes against having the method called immediately when the user's finger touches the screen. Also, if the user touches the button, slides the finger outside of the button's image, then lifts, the method will not be called.
   The ":" means that you are going to pass a value to that method, and the system actually does this for you. It will send the touched button as the parameter passed to "numberSelected:"

   A UIButton is a subclass of UIControl, and the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` method is explained in detail in that part of the documentation.